# (WiX) Install same file to multiple locations

Tags: wix, wix3.5

For several files in my product, I need them copied to two distinct destinations upon installation.  For example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My App\foo\xyzzy.txt
C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My App\bar\xyzzy.txt
```

These two copies of xyzzy.txt are identical.

I'd prefer not to take the size hit of having identical copies of the file in the cabinet.  Playing with makecab, it seems having duplicate copies of files in a cab effectively doubles the size of the cab.  By comparison, 7zip manages to include the second copies with almost no cost in size.

Is it possible to have one copy of each file in the (embedded) cabinet and to install it to two different destinations?  If so, how would you specify that in WiX 3.5?

I assume that having two File elements with the same Id would run afoul of XML's rules and/or the WiX component rules.  On the other hand, if I have unique File elements, will light simply put two copies of the same file in the cabinet?

Comment: Take a look at [why smart cabbing rocks](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/6/1/quotsmart-cabbingquot-added-to-wix-toolset).

Comment: I don't light would duplicate a file if it is used in two File elements. Have you tried using unique File elements with the same Source as Tom suggested?

Comment: As a side note. If the files are and always will be the same (e.g they logically behave as part of a single component) then you should use the CopyFile table rather then creating 2 components.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, [WiX 3 does this](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/6/1/quotsmart-cabbingquot-added-to-wix-toolset) automatically. Just use the same Source attribute in the different File elements. And, yes, you have to give the File elements different Id attributes.

Comment: This seems like the answer, but it fails ICE validation if the directories are not resolved at compile time. I am doing a conditional install which reads several registry keys. For each of the registry keys that are present at install time, i am installing a copy of the file in that location. I spent all day setting it up (yes, with different file ids), and I'm pretty sure I got it right. When I compile, it says "ICE30: The target file '[...]' is installed in '[TARGETDIR]\' by two different components on an LFN system. [...] This breaks reference counting." So, I have no way to tell Wix that t

Comment: @Jon This seems like a new question. What directories are the components targeted to before the registry searches? Are they unique?